# Creating fixed height footer using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am creating a container using a flexbox with 3 rows which includes a header, the body and the footer. The height of the header and footer must remain fixed while the body portion can vary and will provide scrolling if its content exceeds it's visible height:

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  Header
  </div>
  <div class="contentBody">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  <span class="footerMessage">Message goes here</span>
  <span class="footerBtn">OK</span>
  <span class="footerBtn">Cancel</span>
  </div>
```

css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 50vh;
}

.header {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.contentBody {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.footerMessage {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footerBtn {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

If you run the fiddle sample and adjust the width of the result that is shown, the height of the footer does not remain fixed. As you make it smaller, the red buttons within the footer don't remain inside the footer. How can I fix this? Thanks a million!

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/bktwkcgk/3/

Comment: Is there a reason you're not setting the height property of your footer like you're doing with your header?

Comment: I tried but it didn't help.

Comment: Why `max-height: 50vh` at  `.container`?

Comment: The container is centered inside its parent but I don't want it taking up more than 50% of the parent's height.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the following properties to your `.footer`:

```
.footer {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Setting a height and min height will ensure that the footer will remain fixed, even with a very small screensize, `overflow: hidden` will make sure that elements outside of your footer will not appear (hiding the overflowing element in question). `white-space: nowrap;` will avoid your footer message being cut off and falling into the second line.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bktwkcgk/4/)

Comment: That's really close. But there is one issue that can arise. If the footer message is lengthy, I need it to wrap. If it wraps, the footer height should increase.  I modified your code but it doesn't give me the result I want:
https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/4hvz7u32/17/

Comment: Mhmmm. that's because there simply 'isnt more space available'

Comment: But if the content body is set to grow, why doesn't it shrink so that there is enough space for the footer?